# Не правильно работают куки

Tags: php

Почему echo выводит всегда 0?

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
/*
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){
    setcookie('user_name', $_GET['name']);
}

if(!empty($_COOKIE['user_name'])){
    echo $_COOKIE['user_name'];
}
*/

$size = 14;

if(!empty($_COOKIE['text_size'])){
    $size = (int)$_COOKIE['text_size'];
}


if(!empty($_POST['size'])){
    $size = (int)$_COOKIE['size'];
    setcookie('text_size', $size);
}


echo $size;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML5</title>
    <style>
        .size{
            font-size: <?php echo $size?>px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <label for="size">Размер шрифта</label>
    <select id="size" name="size">
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="70">70</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Применить</button>
</form>

<p class="size">Добро пожаловать</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$size = (int)$_COOKIE['size'];`  -> `$size = (int)$_POST['size'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php):

> setcookie() задает cookie, которое будет передано клиенту вместе с
>   другими HTTP заголовками

То есть вы увидите правильное значение `$_COOKIE['size']` только после перезагрузки страницы, сразу же в суперглобальной переменной `$_COOKIE` это значение не добавляется.
Чтобы сразу значение было там доступно предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```
if(!empty($_POST['size'])){
    $size = (int)$_POST['size'];
    setcookie('text_size', $size);
    $_COOKIE['size'] = $size;
}
```

Вариант не лучший, но рабочий.

И так же в вашем случае у вас ошибка в коде, вот правильный вариант:

```
if(!empty($_POST['size'])){
    $size = (int)$_POST['size'];
    setcookie('text_size', $size);
}
```